# Magento 2 Associate Certified Developer Progtis Ended?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, certification

Anyone known that adobe ended the Magento Associated Certification Program?(Magento 2 Associate Certified Developer Exam).

If Not, Then guide me which program is alternate of Magento 2 Associate Certified Developer Exam?

Thanks...

Comment: the name has been changed to adobe certified professional - magento commerce developer

Answer (score 1):

***Associate Developer*** is now called ***Adobe Certified Professional*** .

They changed the names of the certifications (see [this article](https://swiftotter.com/certifications/magento-adobe-certification-transition-updates#/) update from AUGUST 17, 2020 *'Certification name change'*).

Please check the list https://learning.adobe.com/certification.html?solution=Adobe%20Magento%20Commerce of all available certifications on Magento.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that on [learning.adobe.com/certification.html?](https://learning.adobe.com/certification.html?) website

Answer (score 0):

the name has been changed to adobe certified professional - magento commerce developer